# Giant velvet mites?

Tags: science-based, biology, insects

Velvet mites are some of the largest mites in the world, with species in the genus *Dinothrombium* reaching 12 mm in length (absolutely massive for a mite). What is the largest possible size a velvet mite could get with their current biology? What is the limit? Mouse sized? Tarantula sized? Basketball sized?

*Note - This is not a question for the largest possible arthropod, it is specifically for the largest possible mite.

[image]

[image source](https://in.c.mi.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=1328308&aid=2865352&from=album&page=1)

Comment: This questions seems more related to biology than worldbuiling, especially considering the very specific focus on mites.

Comment: There are similar questions on worldbuilding about spiders and velvet worms.

Comment: OMG i never knew such a thing existed

Answer (score 1):

12 mm seems to be the answer. An easy way to think about it is that if a key aspect of their survival is being the largest of their species, it would make sense that they would selectively breed larger and larger until they hit a plateau. Unless a significant mutation event occurs, where somehow their body would be able to support a larger system, they will be locked at 12mm with their current biology.

Comment: Note that beside their own biology, the environment is also key. A higher oxygen concentration in air will allow for bigger size (like on past Earth for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meganeura, 300My ago)

Answer (score 1):

The red velvet mite lives a section of its life as a parasite on other insect drinking their blood, so the main problem is simply if they have a food source big enough that scaling up would make sense, as being a parasite they lack little reason to scale up with their prey during that period, perhaps the size gain would be to make to most and out compete but at this point we have already needed to hit arthropod giants, however in their second phase of life they act as predators and hunt small insects, so there is the option that the size gain happens in this stage but their habit to lay dormant until rainy season would complicate this a bit as with a size increase they would be more likely to be preyed upon as their burrows would be more noticed and they are more worthwhile to hunt. Furthermore as with all arthropods molting becomes increasingly difficult as you age,hence why lobsters aren't truly immortal. Another main problem, or easy fix depending on how you see it, Is the act of breathing through tracheae or in some mite cases directly though skin. This makes arthropods highly susceptible to fluctuations in oxygen unlike lung users who it affects less, hence why despite lower oxygen then in the past we have mammalian megafauna and tiny bugs. So all in all their size depends on, prey size, oxygen levels, and ability to hide out dry season.

oh and in mating the male offers a sperm pack in between twigs and grass and a silk trail to get the females to find it and other males will destroy these trails if they find them.... so if they get too big, trees I guess?
and depending on species they lay from 60 to 100,000 eggs.